# Disastrous bug when running jinfo and jmap

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, jmap, jinfo

When I run jinfo or jmap to any Java process, it will "suspend" the Java process. It's 100% reproduced for the long running processes.

Here're the detailed steps:

1. Pick a Java process which is running over 25 days(It's wired because this doesn't work for new processes).
2. Run ps to check the state of the process, should be "Sl" which is expected.
3. Run jinfo or jmap to this process(BTY, jstack doesn't have this issue).
4. Run ps to check the state of the process. This time it changes to "Tl" which means STOPPED and the process doesn't response any requests.

Here's the output of our process:

```
[work@hadoop ~]$ ps aux |grep "qktst" |grep "RegionServer"
work     36663  0.1  1.7 24157828 1150820 ?    Sl   Aug06  72:54 /opt/soft/jdk/bin/java -cp /home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package//:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package//lib/*:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package//* -Djava.library.path=:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package/lib/native/:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64 -Xbootclasspath/p:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package/lib/hadoop-security-2.0.0-mdh1.1.0.jar -Xmx10240m -Xms10240m -Xmn1024m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xloggc:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/stdout/regionserver_gc_20140806-211157.log -Xss256k -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/log -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=10000 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=80 -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=100 -XX:GCLogFileSize=128m -XX:CMSWaitDuration=2000 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:ConcGCThreads=16 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16 -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=2097088 -XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+SafepointTimeout -XX:MonitorBound=16384 -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=3 -Dproc_regionserver -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/jaas.conf -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhbase.log.dir=/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/log -Dhbase.pid=36663 -Dhbase.cluster=qktst-qk -Dhbase.log.level=debug -Dhbase.policy.file=hbase-policy.xml -Dhbase.home.dir=/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/krb5.conf -Dhbase.id.str=work org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer start
[work@hadoop ~]$ jinfo 36663 > tobe.jinfo
Attaching to process ID 36663, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 20.12-b01
[work@hadoop ~]$ ps aux |grep "qktst" |grep "RegionServer"
work     36663  0.1  1.7 24157828 1151008 ?    Tl   Aug06  72:54 /opt/soft/jdk/bin/java -cp /home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package//:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package//lib/*:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package//* -Djava.library.path=:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package/lib/native/:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64 -Xbootclasspath/p:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package/lib/hadoop-security-2.0.0-mdh1.1.0.jar -Xmx10240m -Xms10240m -Xmn1024m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xloggc:/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/stdout/regionserver_gc_20140806-211157.log -Xss256k -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/log -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=10000 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=80 -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=100 -XX:GCLogFileSize=128m -XX:CMSWaitDuration=2000 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:ConcGCThreads=16 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16 -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=2097088 -XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+SafepointTimeout -XX:MonitorBound=16384 -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=3 -Dproc_regionserver -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/jaas.conf -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhbase.log.dir=/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/log -Dhbase.pid=36663 -Dhbase.cluster=qktst-qk -Dhbase.log.level=debug -Dhbase.policy.file=hbase-policy.xml -Dhbase.home.dir=/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/package -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/home/work/app/hbase/qktst-qk/regionserver/krb5.conf -Dhbase.id.str=work org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer start
```

It may be the bug of JVM but I don't get any response after I reported this to oracle. So I hope some JVM experts here could help.

> $ java -version
>   java version "1.6.0_37"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: This is known behaviour - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287010/is-jvm-stopped-while-executing-jmap I believe that the fact that it suspends for a noticeable time on the long running process is because the heap is significantly more complicated and thus will take longer to obtain the information. `jstack -F` *should* also exhibit similar behaviour.

Comment: Thank @Petesh and I can understand these commands must take time to get the info from jvm. But now our processes have been suspended for several days. Is it abnormal, right?

Comment: And `jstack -F` has the same behaviour while `jstack` not. I think there're some reasons that prevent the processes recovering.

Comment: Stuck permanently after running the command was not obvious from the question. It does sound like a tools bug, but you're probably not going to get any response from Oracle unless you have extended support. There are way too many other considerations here (e.g. Linux kernel version; JNI code; manually hooked signal handling code) which could be causing the interaction. I'd just encode a workaround that sends a `kill -CONT <pid>` (perhaps more than once) to get it past the issue.

Comment: Thank @Petesh. Can you reproduce this issue in your machine? Now I'm considering something about ptrace. Our kernel version is 2.6.32-279.23.1 and I don't know is there any issue there.

Comment: I'm stock 3.0.17 kernel, and 1.6u24 JVMs and have never seen this happen on any of our systems (some of which have > 60 day uptime on the java processes). That kernel revision indicates RHEL, which is heavily customised; Following the call, can you check the state of `grep State /proc/<pid>/task/*/status` - it could be a missing `ptrace(DETACH)` in jmap which is triggering the bug.

Comment: I can see every status is stopped, like **21559/status:State:     T (stopped)**.
And I see this http://ebergen.net/wordpress/2008/06/25/ptrace-on-threads-and-linux-signal-handling-issues/.