# Tomcat java8 linux get the heap dump for a running instance

Tags: tomcat, memory-management, java-8, heap-dump

In one of my web applications there is an issue:

I want to check whether objects are properly initialized or not.

For that I want to extract a memory dump and analyse it . How can I take a memory dump in Tomcat and analyse it ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Get Tomcat (Bootstrap) process ID by jps command

```
# jps
24717 Jps
3652 Bootstrap
3737 DirectoryServer
```

(2) Run jmap command

```
# jmap -dump:format=b,file=./heapdump.hprof 3652
```

(3) Download [Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

(4) Open heapdump.hprof by MAT

Comment: Will jmap hang tomcat or kill/stop tomcat ? I want to take dump in running application.

Comment: No. You can do it in running application.

Comment: And shall I stop the app manually ? If I stop then there is no way to get the heap dump of stopped app since no heap is in memory for that process now. Does jmap will internally stop/terminate  the app ?

Comment: No. Heap dump can be got during running app.

Comment: How in running app ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287010/is-jvm-stopped-while-executing-jmap - jmap stops running application here.

Comment: Your application cannot response as usual while running jmap but the process is not killed.

Comment: any alternative to jmap ?