# Threads and fork(). How can I deal with that?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, fork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fork in multi-threaded program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235516/fork-in-multi-threaded-program)

If I have an application which employs fork() and might be developed as multithreaded, what are the thumb rules/guidelines to consider to safely program this kind of applications?

Comment: @JensGustedt I originally though so too, but this should be more along the lines of a comprehensive question about threads and _fork()_ on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic thumb rules, according to various internet articles like ( http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them , [fork in multi-threaded program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235516/fork-in-multi-threaded-program) ) are:

1. *(Main) Process[0] Monothread --> fork() --> (Child) Process[1] Multithreaded*: **OK!**
   If *Process[1]* crashes or messes around with memory it *won't* touch address space of *Process[0]* (unless you use shared R/W memory... but this is another topic of its own).
   In Linux by default all *fork()ed* memory is [Copy On Write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). Given that *Process[0]* is monothreaded, when we invoke *fork()* all possible mutual exclusion primitives should be *generally* in an *unlocked* state.
2. *(Main) Process[0] Multithreaded --> fork() --> (Child) Process[1] Mono/Multithread*: **BAD!**
   If you *fork()* a Multithreaded process your mutexes and many other thread synchronization primitives will likely be in an *undefined state* in Process[1]. You can work around with *pthread_atfork()* but if you use libraries you might as well roll a dice and hope to be lucky. Because generally you don't (want to) know the implementation details of libraries.

The advantages of *fork()* into a multithreaded process are that you could manipulate/read/aggregate your data quicker (in the Child process), without having to care about stability of the process you *fork()* from (Main). This is useful if your main process has a dataset of *a lot* of memory and you don't want to duplicate/reload it to safely process the data in another process (Child). This way the original process is stable and independent from the data aggregation/manipulation process (*fork()ed*).

Of course this means that the original process *will generally* be slower than it might be if developed in multithreaded fashion. But again, this is the price you might want to be paying for more stability.

If instead your main process is multithreaded, *refrain* from using *fork()*. It's going to be a *proper mess* to implement it in a stable way.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, threads are implemented in terms of processes. In other words, threads are really just a `fork()` with mostly shared memory, instead of completely copy-on-write memory. What this means, is that when you use `fork()` in a thread (main or other), you end up copying the entire shared memory space of all of the threads, and the thread specific storage of the thread you call `fork()` from.

Now all of this sounds good, but that doesn't mean that this is what will happen or work well. If you want to make a cloned process, try to do a fork before starting any other threads, and then use read-only virtual memory to keep the forked process up to date with current memory values.

So although it may work, I just suggest testing, and try to find another way first. And be prepared for a lot of:

```
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Still threads and processes, even with linux, have very different semantics. In particular, on crashing, where a crashing thread will take all others with him and a crashing process can be handle with. I don't have the feeling that your answer is particularly helpful for the original question and should have been put in a comment.

Comment: @Linuxios Thanks for this additional explanation about how threads are created under Linux, but shouldn't be _clone()_ call that is technically used? I think it's a bit confusing in overall terms. Cheers

Comment: @Emanuele: That's exactly what I ment. The clone call.