# Multithreaded program and fork(): alternative or safe implementation

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

In a multithreaded Linux/C++-program, I want to use `fork()` with a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`.

In the child process I use `open()` to create two new file descriptors, `sendfile()` and `close()`, then the child exits.

I planned to use `fork()` to implement the following requirements:

The threads in the parent process shall be able to

1. detect the normal termination of the child process, and in that case shall be able to create another `fork()` doing the `open()/sendfile()/close()` for a range of files
2. kill the `sendfile()`-child process in case of a specific event and detect the intentional termination to clean up

For requirement 1 I could just wait for the result of `sendfile()`.
Requirement 2 is why I think I need to use `fork()` in the first place.

After reading the following posts

- [Threads and fork(). How can I deal with that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868724/threads-and-fork-how-can-i-deal-with-that)
- [fork in multi-threaded program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235516/fork-in-multi-threaded-program)

I think that my solution might not be a good one.

My questions are:

- Is there any other solution to implement requirement 2 ?
- Or how can I make sure that the library calls `open(), close() and sendfile()` will be okay?

*Update:*

- The program will run on a Busybox Linux / ARM
- I've assumed that I should use `sendfile()` for having the most efficient file transfer due to several posts I've read regarding this topic.
  A safe way to implement my requirement could be using `fork()` and `exec*()` with `cp`, with the disadvantage that the file transfer might be less efficient

*Update 2:*

- it's sufficient to `fork()` once in case of a specific event (instead of once per file) since I switched to `exec*()` with `rsync` in the child process. However the program needs invoke that `rsync` always in case of a specific event.

Comment: Or just use read/write on a background thread instead of fork.

Comment: Forking from a multithreaded program has undefined behaviour in general. More specifically, the forked child is in an async-signal context in which the only permissible operations are (essentially) exit or exec. What you can very decidedly *not* do is something like memory allocation.

Comment: @RichardCritten: I don't know of any way to tell the bg thread to stop while it's waiting for the `sendfile()` to return, and I don't want to wait in case a huge file is processed

Comment: @radix that's why read/write

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What do you mean with read/write? I don't get how I can abort a `sendfile()`, or a `system()` for `cp` / `rsync` which is started in the background thread. As I see it the background thread will invoke the `system( "rsync...")` and will have to wait until it returns.

Answer (score 3):

You can use threads, but forcefully terminating threads typically leads to memory leaks and other problems.

My linux experience is somewhat limited, but I would probably try to **fork the program early**, before it gets multithreaded. Now that you have two instances, the single threaded instance can be safely used to manage the starting and stopping of additional instances.

Comment: That probably could be a solution if considered at start of development, but unfortunately it extremely affects the design of the SW in my case.

Comment: I think you will have to explain more why that is the case. You are aware that you can use shared memory and similar for interprocess communication? The forked instances need to have the data required to accomplish their tasks. Do you require other resources than just data?

Comment: One issue is that the "transfer thread" receives a pointer to a class instance for reporting errors. The log function is also used by other classes whose instances run in the main thread. This could basically be solved via IPC, like the rest of the configuration for the thread. I hoped to find a simpler solution.