# Threads and fork: fgetc() blocks when reading from popen()-pipe

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

In a multithreaded program (running on ARM) I have

**a main thread** which, among other things, periodically checks with `popen( "pidof -s prog" )` whether another program is running. I use the `O_CLOEXEC` flag for the file descriptor and check whether `fgetc()` receives anything from the pipe. *Setting the file descriptor "non-blocking" results in nothing being read and won't help*. The same `pidof` command from the shell command is performing fine.

**In another thread**, `fork()` with an immediate `execl()` in the child process is used to start an `rsync` operation whenever a specific event occurs. The parent uses a signal handler to observe the child status, and has the option to kill the child at another specific event. It doesn't matter whether I invoke `exec()` with `rsync` or `sleep` - the result is the same.

The problem is that the `fgetc()` in the main thread blocks until the child process terminates.

*I'll try to solve this problem by `fork()`ing early (at some point where the application is single-threaded, as supposed in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891437/multithreaded-program-and-fork-alternative-or-safe-implementation) which I started).*

But anyway:

**I'd like to understand what's causing the `fgetc()` to block when reading from the pipe.**

A few things I've tried so far:

- I tried to reproduce the problem with a small example application that does what I've described above and hoped it would show the same erroneous behaviour, but *unfortunately* it works fine, which is why I do not provide any code here yet. Maybe I'm missing the relevant point.
- Using the same `rsync` invocation via `system()` doesn't cause any issues
- I've had a look at a `system()` [implementation](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/procexec/system.c.html) and can see that the signals are manipulated before `fork()`ing:

  - SIGCHLD is blocked
  - SIGINT and SIGQUIT are ignored

  I need the signal handler for SIGCHLD, but out of curiousity I tried to do the same as in the code from above (I replaced `sigprocmask()` with `pthread_sigmask()` ) - without any success, the behaviour stays the same.

  I couldn't find any implementation of `system()` in the sources provided with my BSP.

The program opens other files via `fstream` - and without O_CLOEXEC (will be a bit [cumbersome to change that](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2004-01/0361.html))

Comment: `system` has nothing to do with kernel sources. It's in your libc.

Comment: True, I've changed it

Comment: What is your question? Assuming it was "what's causing the `fgetc()` to block when reading from the pipe", has your edit now solved it? If so, it would be better to move that out into an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've posted the edit so people stop wasting their time for the question for now. It seems that it's fixed, however I'd like to run some tests to be sure before posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bugfix and explanation of unexpected behaviour**

Indeed I've missed the relevant point. After adapting the sample program more to the original code example I've seen that the signal handler (which worked in a test program) was the issue. Excerpt:

```
void MyClass::sig_handler(int sig) {
    if( m_pid < 1 ) // not the child we're waiting for
        return;

    pid_t pid;
    int wstatus;

    while ((pid = waitpid( -1, &wstatus, WNOHANG )) != -1 ) {
        // error: this returns 0 as long as any children are alive
        // -> check for "> 0" to ignore active child processes
        if( pid != m_pid )
            return;
        // handle stuff here...
    }
}
```

I had to replace the following line

```
while ((pid = waitpid( -1, &wstatus, WNOHANG )) != -1 )
```

with

```
while ((pid = waitpid( -1, &wstatus, WNOHANG )) > 0 )
```

because the program's other threads `fork()` children (e.g. with `popen()`). If those terminate, the signal handler (a static class function) is invoked, too.

As I understand:

In the thread where I invoke `fork()`, I use a member `m_pid` with default and reset value `-1`. It takes the pid from `fork()`. The sig handler immediately returns if `m_pid` is -1.

The program blocked at `popen()` which `fork()`s (could be any other call that `fork()`s). Thus the signal handler for SIGCHLD is entered when `popen()` returns. The check for `m_pid` is passed as `m_pid = fork()` has been invoked. `waitpid()` does not return -1 but the pid of the `popen()` child, and then keeps checking with return value = 0 until all children have terminated - the one I'm waiting for is still alive! Only then `waitpid()` returns with `-1` and the main thread can continue reading with `fgetc()`.

Man page from `waitpid`:

> if WNOHANG was  specified  and  one  or  more child(ren) specified by pid 
>   exist, but have not yet changed state, then 0 is returned.  On error, -1 
>   is returned

Because the sig handler checks for `m_pid != -1`, the problem only occurred when I used `fork()` in MyClass to set the `m_pid`.

That's why using `system()` did not cause the problem. The `m_pid` is not set to a value != -1, thus the sig handler immediately returns if e.g. a child is `popen()`ed in the main thread.

The *imitation* of the `system()` invocation failed because I've set the  `m_pid` at `fork()`, thus the sig handler did not return immediately.

I guess since the sig handler is a `static member function`, the handler blocks the very thread that `fork()`ed a child process.