# Python multiprocessing blocking unexpectedly

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, blocking

I'm running a python script using apache and modpython on a Linux environment. It integrates in a web tool which allow file processing. The part of my script that includes file processing can have very long execution time. In the original version of my code, the script waits for the files to be processed, and at the end it returns some html with a link to download the resulting file.

submit.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./my_script.py/main" method="post">
            <div> <input type="file" name="file"> </div>
            <div> <input type="submit" value="Upload"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my_script.py

```
def main(file):
    process(file)
    return "<p> Download your file <a href='./%s'></a>", % file

def process(file)
    #some file treatment here, and a resulting file is stored in current directory
```

I want to write a feature which would allow the user to receive the resulting file by email. In that case once he has uploaded his file, I would like to redirect him to a page, he could keep on using the web tool, while his file is being processed server sided and thus the user is not being Unix forks. I have made several tests with these 3 options but I always get blocked by the running script. For what I have understood, multiprocessing is best suited for my case, so I have tried this:

my_script.py

```
def main(file, receiver_mail_address):
    p = Process(target=process_and_email, args=(file, receiver_mail_address)
    p.start()
    return "<p> The resulting files will be emailed to you at %s.</p>" % receiver_mail_address

def process_and_email(file, receiver_mail_address):
    #some file processing here, and emailing. these functions work perfectly as expected.
```

In this situation I have skipped the `p.join()` step which is said in the python docs to

> "Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is
>   called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs."

But in my case, it is still blocked. It means I have to wait for my process `p` to being over before reaching the `return` statement. How could I do that ?

---

Edit :

I have tried to change to the `subprocess` module. So I have put the `process_and_email` function into a new file called process_and_email.py and I modified the main script :

my_script.py

```
def main(file, receiver_mail_address):
    directory = os.path.firname(__file__)
    path = os.path.join(directory, 'process_and_email.py')

    subprocess.Popen(['python2.7', path, file, receiver_mail_address], shell=True)

    return "<p> The resulting files will be emailed to you at %s.</p>" % receiver_mail_address
```

I still have the same problem : I cannot reached the `return` statement before the process_and_email.py file has been totally executed.

Comment: Are you using thread locks or the `logging` module? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235516/fork-in-multi-threaded-program) question about why forking and multi-threading don't get along very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your parent process won't exit until all non-daemon child processes have completed the work they're doing. So in your case, `process_and_email` needs to complete before the script can exit, even though `main` has completed. You can make the child process a daemon, which will allow the parent script to exit right away, but it will kill the worker process prior to exiting, which isn't what you want either.

I think a better option for you is to use the `subprocess` module to spawn a separate Python script to do your processing in the background. That way your parent script can exit, and leave the worker process running.

Comment: I have modified my script by using the subprocess module :

I have moved my function `process_and_email` into a new .py file and used the `subprocess.Popen()` command to call it, but I still have the very same problem : my script wont reach the `return` statement before the script is done. 

Once again this is the very contrary of what the doc seems to be telling !

Comment: @VanPommel Edit your question to include the subprocess code you're using.

Comment: @VanPommel Run it like this: `subprocess.Popen(['python2.7', path, file, receiver_mail_address], shell=False)`. I took your script and after making just that change (`shell=False`, instead of `shell=True`), it works fine for me. With `shell=True` it actually opened the Python interactive prompt, because when you use `shell=True` you should pass your args as a string, not a list.

Comment: I did exactly as you said and this is still not working for me. Maybe this is not a Python issue, something linked to Modpython or Apache or Firefox ... ?

Comment: @VanPommel Hmm, yeah, maybe. Try running your script directly in Python, just to verify it works when run outside of the Apache environment.

Comment: Finally, this solution is working absolutely fine. The blocking processing I was assuming was the `process_and_email`, was actually another function prior to it, which was obviously a software misconception of mine.

The beanstalk solution suggested by Midnighter works fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern used in web applications is to maintain a global queue, for example, [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) which has a nice Python interface called [beanstalkc](https://github.com/earl/beanstalkc/blob/master/TUTORIAL.mkd). You would then submit such jobs to the queue and have a separate program/process watch that queue and work on items in the queue.