# How can I promote a thread to child process in Rust?

Tags: process, rust, stderr

I need to write something similar to compiletest. Compiletest works by invoking the `rustc` process and capturing stdout/stderr. My project does not have a binary to run yet, so I need another way to create a subprocess.

I can't use a channel nor stdout because it's not controlled by my code.

Comment: Is it even possible? I never heard about it

Comment: @Boiethios I expected something like child process api in some scripting languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I promote a thread to child process

You cannot. This is simply something that operating systems don't *do*; it's not specific to Rust. You cannot start an arbitrary thread and then move it ("promote it") to another process later; threads and processes are very different concepts.

> My project does not have a binary to run yet

I suggest making one.

---

If you wish to simply start another process, you can use [`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) for that. This would be the most recommended option.

POSIX does have the [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) call, which duplicates the *entire* memory of the process and the *current* thread, so theoretically you could use this to "promote" the current thread to a new process.

[Using this in a multithreaded context can be very complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1235516/155423) and basically will always be recommended against by default.

[Support for `fork` on Windows is... limited, at best](https://stackoverflow.com/q/985281/155423). If you only care about POSIX systems, you can use [`fork` from the libc crate](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.36/libc/fn.fork.html).

See also:

- [fork man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)
- [fork in multi-threaded program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1235516/155423)
- [What is the closest thing windows has to fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/985281/155423)

---

> capturing stdout/stderr

There *are* hidden, unstable methods for changing the current threads `stdout` / `stderr`. Rust's testing framework uses these methods. If you'd be interested in making these stable, you could perhaps [offer to help on the tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31343).

Comment: Then.. how does node child process work? Does it just spawn other 
 instance of `node` executable with different parameter?

Comment: Oh.. that make sense.. And I guess that's why only scripting languages has such multi process apis.

Comment: I just want to capture stderr of test, and diff it with expected output. I don't care if it runs in separate process, but stderr is per process so I thought I have to somehow create a process for each test.

Comment: [`fork`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.36/libc/fn.fork.html) "promotes" a copy of the current thread to a new process.  How does that not fit the question? (Although I wouldn't recommend using `fork` in multi-thread context.)

Comment: @Stefan you have a good point, I just didn't think `fork` was relevant to OPs actual situation as it sounded like they wanted to move *another* thread to a process (plus it is platform-dependent). I might as well add it for completeness.